# how do I get a date stored in a database as a string in Clojure?

Tags: json, clojure, clojure-java-interop

When getting values back out of a Postgres database with clojure.java.jdbc, I'm ending up with

`{:id 1, :name "example", :created_at #object[java.time.LocalDateTime 0x15e0aadc "2019-02-08T12:52:11.438633"]}`

when I want

`{:id 1, :name "example", :created_at :created_at "2019-02-08T12:52:11.438633"]}`

I want the date to be returned as JSON and consumable by JavaScript. The second example may not be the ideal format for that and so I'm open to others, but a Java object is not going to work.

I tried a couple of approaches, but the compiler produced a number of 'unmatched parenthesis' errors as a result of the date #object.

Thoughts on how to do this? Do I do something with the original SQL query, do I do something with my returned data, or something else?

Comment: And what are you using to serialize your map as JSON? Can it not handle datetimes?

Comment: I was using the clojure.data.json write-str function which in produced the following error:

```1. Unhandled java.lang.Exception
   Don't know how to write JSON of class java.time.LocalDateTime```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried recreating your result with the H2 db, but it is giving me a Clojure `#inst` result instead of an object reference.

---

OK, here is the problem.  As your printout says, you have a `java.time.LocalDateTime` (a Clojure `#inst` is a `java.util.Date` object).

If you want a string version, all you need to do is call the member function `toString` on it:

```
  (let [ldt (LocalDateTime/parse "2019-02-01T00:00:00" )]

    (.toString ldt) => <#java.lang.String "2019-02-01T00:00">
```

However, you have no Time Zone information attached.  So, you probably want a ZonedDateTime.  **WE WILL ASSUME UTC TIME ZONE BELOW** (please verify for your DB server config):

```
  (let [jud      (Date.)
        ldt      (LocalDateTime/parse "2019-02-01T00:00:00")
        zdt      (.atZone ldt (ZoneId/of "UTC"))  ; *** big assumption here! ***
        inst     (.toInstant zdt)
        inst-str (.toString inst) ]

    ; a Clojure #inst is just a java.util.Date object
    jud      =>  #inst "2019-02-09T19:38:30.088-00:00"   

    ; a ZonedDateTime can print in 2 ways
    zdt              => #object[java.time.ZonedDateTime 0x780af31 "2019-02-01T00:00Z[UTC]"]
    (.toString zdt)  => "2019-02-01T00:00Z[UTC]"

    ; a java.time.Instant also prints in 2 ways:
    instant          => #object[java.time.Instant 0x48301adb "2019-02-01T00:00:00Z"]
    instant-str      => "2019-02-01T00:00:00Z"
```

Note that the ZDT has a suffix like `[UTC]` tacked onto the end, so you may wish to convert it to an Instant and then use the `.toString` method to get a simpler string representation of it (ISO-8601).

---

If you don't mind using an external library to make this easier, the `tupelo.java-time` lib has a helper function that is very handy:

```
(ns xyz
  (require [tupelo.java-time :as tjt] ... ))

(tjt/string-date-time-iso zdt) => "2019-02-01T00:00:00Z"
```

There are many other helper functions available.  Please see [the API Docs](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.java-time.html) and [the unit tests for examples](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/java_time.clj).

---

## Update

I finally got my Postgres install fixed up (had to reset the password to make Hikari work).  Here is my test code:

```
(ns tst.demo.jdbc-pool
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
    [hikari-cp.core :as pool]
    [tupelo.java-time :as tjt] ) )

(def datasource-options-pg
  {:adapter       "postgresql"
   :database-name "alan"
   :server-name   "localhost"
   :port-number   5433
   :username      "alan"
   :password      "secret" } )

(def ^:dynamic db-conn nil)

(defn with-connection-pool
  "Creates and uses a connection for test function"
  [tst-fn]
  (let [datasource (pool/make-datasource datasource-options-pg)]
    (binding [db-conn {:datasource datasource}]
      (tst-fn)
      (pool/close-datasource datasource)))) ; close the connection - also closes/destroys the in-memory database

(use-fixtures
  :once with-connection-pool) ; use the same db connection pool for all tests
```

The above is all just config stuff.  Here is the unit test that verifies the behavior:

```
(dotest
  (jdbc/db-do-commands db-conn ["drop table if exists langs"])
  (jdbc/db-do-commands db-conn
    [(jdbc/create-table-ddl :langs [[:id :serial]
                                    [:lang "varchar not null"]
                                    [:creation :timestamptz]])])
  (jdbc/insert-multi! db-conn :langs
    [{:lang "Clojure" :creation (tjt/iso-str->timestamp "2008-01-01T12:34:56Z")}
     {:lang "Java"    :creation (tjt/iso-str->timestamp "1995-06-01T07:08:09Z")}])

  (let [result (jdbc/query db-conn ["select * from langs"])]
    (is=  (vec result)
      [{:id       1, :lang "Clojure",
        :creation #inst "2008-01-01T12:34:56.000000000-00:00"}
       {:id       2, :lang "Java",
        :creation #inst "1995-06-01T07:08:09.000000000-00:00"}])))
```

So you can see I am still getting a `java.util.Date` result, which Clojure prints with the `#inst` formatting.  I'm not sure how you are getting JDBC to output the `LocalDateTime` format.

Comment: Thank you for your really complete answer! The .toString worked. 

The UTC need is something hadn't considered yet. I'll give Tupelo a try, too.

Answer (score 2):

I’d imagine that cheshire.core/encode would give you nice JSON from that map.

Read more about cheshire at https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire

Comment: I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 1):

Extend the java.time.Instant in your db.core.clj file. See https://rundis.github.io/blog/2015/clojure_dates.html for examples on extending types and protocols.

```
(extend-type java.time.Instant
  jdbc/ISQLParameter
  (set-parameter [v ^PreparedStatement stmt ^long idx]
    (.setTimestamp stmt idx (Timestamp. (.toEpochMilli v)))))

(extend-protocol cheshire.generate/JSONable
  java.time.Instant
  (to-json [dt gen]
    (cheshire.generate/write-string gen (str dt))))
```